# Android SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost() does not cause redraw

Tags: java, android, draw, surfaceview

I'm implementing a fairly standard app with the Android sdk that involves drawing using the SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder, Callback setup.

In my main thread (UI thread) I have no drawing or handling of the SurfaceHolder (or the canvas you retrieve with it).

In a separate thread I have the following:

```
Log.i("GAME.DrawThread", "run()");
        Log.i("GAME.DrawThread", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(holder) {
                Log.i("GAME", "draw():synchronized");
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(R.color.draw_color);
                canvas.drawColor(R.color.draw_color);
                canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500, paint);
            }
        } catch (SurfaceHolder.BadSurfaceTypeException e) {
            Log.e("GAME", "onDraw():  BadSurfaceTypeException");
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
```

This code is being executed, throws no exceptions, and has no negative side effects that I can find; however, the unlockCanvasAndPost() call never causes onDraw() to be called.

In other words, unlockCanvasAndPost() does not cause a redraw of the SurfaceView.

Any ideas what could cause this symptom?  I have plenty of java experience, a fair amount of android experience, and a lot of debugging experience and cannot track this one down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code now crashes in Android 4.3

Answer (score 13):

So it turns out that when using SurfaceView you draw to a Surface that is underneath a Window.  I was setting the background color of the View in xml; it turns out that sets the background color of the Window, not the Surface.  In effect, I made the Window opaque so that you couldn't see the Surface underneath.

Lesson Learned.

Comment: Wow, thanks for following up!  I had the same problem and don't know how long it would've taken to find it.  I spent a few hours on it before I found the solution here.  Ugh.

Comment: I've been hours digging for an answer why the `unlockCanvasAndPost()`would not refresh the screen although all drawing methods were executed... Finally came across your answer and realized it was my equal issue, I was setting a black background for the view and the surfaceview was drawing beneath it.. I nearly went mad already :P

Answer (score 0):

That's not how SurfaceView works. Calling unlockCanvasAndPost() does not invoke onDraw(), that's the whole point of using a SurfaceView. A SurfaceView's surface lives in a different window.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem.  Whatever mechanism that is used for posting the canvas you write to to the screen is not being invoked.

Comment: You don't explain what the problem is. How is it not working?

Comment: Yes Romain Guy please help us solving this conundrum :p

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I have a feeling the problem is there is no surfaceholder callback. He was trying to draw on the surface before the surface was created

Answer (score 0):

For set SurfaceView to top Z-View index, add to youre CustomerSurfaceView a code below:

```
init {
   setZOrderOnTop(true)
}
```